# как в modx revo сделать вывод определенных товаров по tv?

Tags: modx

использую mfilter2 тока незнаю как сделать вывод определенных товаров

```
[[!mFilter2? 
                &filters=`tv|price_from:decimal,tv|metro`
                &toSeparatePlaceholders=`ms.`
                &suggestions=`0`
                &parents=[[*id]]
                &depth=`3`
                &includeTVs=`metro,price_from,price_to,area,city,direction,
                        mcad_distance,metro_distance,type_of_sale,currency,
                        image,square_from,square_to,main_page_show,
                        class_zdaniya,nazvanie_zdaniya,tip_zdaniya,
                        main_page_show`
                &tvPrefix=`tv.`
                &tpl=`catalogItem_sidebar`
                &where=`{"template":7}`
                &limit=`12`
                &sortby=`{"main_page_show":"DESC","publishedon":"DESC","createdon":"DESC"}`
                &tplFilter.outer.tv|metro=`tpl.mFilter2.filter.outerGiga`
                &tplFilter.row.tv|metro=`tpl.mFilter2.filter.checkboxHalfCol`

            ]]

<div id="mse2_results">
                            [[!+ms.results]]
                        </div>
```

Так же хотелось бы знать, я создал 50+ страниц с определенными ссылками, не хотелось бы в ручную создавать столько шаблонов для этих страниц, как можно хитрым способом это обойти?
например на каждой странице сделать доп поле метро и поставив галочку делает первоначальную выборку по этому метро

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с выборкой товаров по названию категории: если параметр товара называется также как и заголовок страницы, на которой его выводят, то показываем товар. Использовался сниппет getProducts. Я по незнанию долго искал способ. В итоге выяснилось, что такой же, как у вас код

```
&where=`{"template":7}`
```

надо писать с двоеточием. Вот мой блок

```
[[!getProducts?
&includeTVs=`1`
&limit=`50`
&depth=`2`
&tpl=`productTplCollection`
&parents=`2`
&tvFilters=`{"collection:=":"[[*pagetitle]]"}`
]]
```

Обратите внимание на tvFilters.